# How to dump all private key from wallet.dat (walletversion > 130000)?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, bip32-hd-wallets, private-key-export

I tried to use `pywallet` and it can't dump all of the wallet's private keys.

When I send 10 transactions & decode raw transactions, I will get 10 new addresses, but I can't dump all of the private keys
without `bitcoind`, normally I'll get first 3 or 4 private key only.

So, how can I extract all private keys? The wallet version of 130000 has new generate key function call "Hierarchical Deterministic Key Generation".

https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0

But I can't find a tool that support it and dump private key without `bitcoind`, anyone can help me?

Comment: I've fixed up the spelling and grammar a bit, but I don't really understand what you meant with the second sentence. Do you mean "addresses" instead of "forked wallets"?

Comment: yep , & many thanx , I mean all used wallets and private keys include forked & mempool